# Mapbox/Maplibre and WMS layer

Tags: javascript, php, cors, mapbox, qgis

I know that question asked many times but I didn't find solution.

I work with MapboxGL/MaplibreGL and when I add WMS layer, the console returns all time

`Access to fetch at 'https://wms.myurl.fr/qgis?map=projects/test_wms1.qgs&bbox=136975.15468703583,5371382.851655904,146759.09430753812,5381166.7912764065&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=carte_moissac' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

For information, this problem come from MaplibreGL (and lonely) because my WMS layer works with LeafletJS.

Headers are present ahead to my php file like that :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
?>
```

How do you go about it?

Thanks

Sylvain

I am looking for to add WMS layers into my app carto.

I am looking for add wms layer into my Mapbox Application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stackexchange REST API has been blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055329/stackexchange-rest-api-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORs on the GeoServer server - see either https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370605/allow-cors-on-geoserver-with-tomcat-and-nginx or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty depending on your server type.